# NextJS meta tags are not rendered via SSR

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have the following component:

```js
// src/pages/s/[county]/[caseNumber].tsx

const CaseNumber = ({
  queryCounty,
  queryCase,
}: {
  queryCounty: string;
  queryCase: string;
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(...);
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta
          property="og:description"
          content={`${queryCase} ${queryCounty}`}
          key="og:description"
        />
        <meta
          property="description"
          content={`${queryCase} ${queryCounty}`}
          key="description"
        />
      </Head>
    </>
  )
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ params }) => {
  return {
    props: {
      queryCounty: params?.county,
      queryCase: params?.caseNumber,
    },
  };
};
```

When I run my app via `next dev` I can see those meta tags rendered perfectly, but if I run `next build && next start` and visit page via curl the tags are not there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code seems to work on my end (Next.js 12.1.0), both `dev` and `build/start`. Which version of Next.js are you using?

Comment: @MarkG I have the same version. I've added info on the file location and useEffect into the question. By the way, how did you test that it's working via `build/start`? Did you run `build`, then `start` and then used curl?

Answer (score 2):

The answer was simple, upper in my tree of components I had something like this:

```
if (!dataLoaded) return <FullscreenLoader />
```

thus, this fullscreen loader was what was loaded from the server, skipping my `<meta>` tags. The solution was to move all those tags into component and load it before that `if` was called